# Can't figure out optimization function that does what I want in gurobi?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm trying to produce a matrix of cubes that are in optimized places. Currently, I want to discourage the program from putting too many of the same ones together.

vars is a 3d array of x,y coordinates and 12 dimensions for z for the 12 options available and a binary decision variable for putting that one in that particular x,y slot.

I have removed the other part of my optimization function and left this troublesome one:

```
m.setObjective(quicksum((-(vars[x,y,z]**3-vars[x,y,z]**2)/20) 
for x0 in range(1,3) 
for y0 in range(1,3) 
for x in range(x0*ed) 
for y in range(y0*ed) 
for z in range(12)))
```

Take note this is normally all on one line, broken up for your convenience and mine. This method of doing for loops inside a gurobi quicksum works, I don't know why nor am I sure if it functions outside of gurobi.

Anyways, I get an "unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Var' and 'int'" error at the function part (**3 and **2).

But ignoring that, I don't even know if the code is doing what I want it to do, so why error correct? I *think* it's summing up variables that are the same z and are within "ed" distance of eachother and then subtracting from the objective function an amount of their value^3-value^2. But I doubt it. Any suggestions?

I don't want to do a constraint because I want to allow for the possibility of three or more of the same type near eachother if that's optimal so no reason to deny it outright. My goal is to punish the function for having too many of a certain type near eachother.

I'm trying to prevent the clusters shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIVk1.jpg

Comment: Gurobi only supports linear and (some) quadratic objectives. I probably would look at a Manhattan distance measure, and only use this for blocks of the same type (that may require a little bit of thought).

Comment: It's not clear how this formulation, even if it were supported, is connected to the actual problem you are trying to solve.  The problem might actually be good fit for Gurobi.  With a more precise description, someone might be able to provide an effective formulation.

Comment: I've been using the manhattan distance for the main formulation of my problem:
m.setObjective(quicksum(vars[x,y,z] * attack[z]*(aw/(3-x)) + vars[x,y,z] * defense[z]*(dw**(abs(x-flagx)+abs(y-flagy))) for x in range(nrow) for y in range(ncol) for z in range(12)))
which I use to get penalize things for being far from the flagx flagy coordinates, but I have no idea how to do this for individual pieces that don't have their coordinates pre-determined outside the solver.

Comment: Gurobi has an `abs_()` function to help you formulate this.